# How to fix connection problems when nothing seems to work

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to my atlas cluster from the mongoshell within the windows terminal. The connection string is correctly written and I made sure that the clusters version (4.0.10) and the shell version (4.0.10) are the same. I have also made sure that my ip address is whitelisted and for testing purposes I have added "0.0.0.0/0" as well. Still it doesn't let me connect.

I have tried creating a new database, change user, create new users, change user permissions, changing ip whitelist, using different connection strings, turning off windows firewall, but still, the same error persists.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://charmsdb-shard-00-02-5s81x.mongodb.net.:27017,charmsdb-shard-00-01-5s81x.mongodb.net.:27017,charmsdb-shard-00-00-5s81x.mongodb.net.:27017/test?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=CharmsDB-shard-0&ssl=true
2019-07-09T12:42:04.136+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for CharmsDB-shard-0/charmsdb-shard-00-02-5s81x.mongodb.net.:27017,charmsdb-shard-00-01-5s81x.mongodb.net.:27017,charmsdb-shard-00-00-5s81x.mongodb.net.:27017
2019-07-09T12:42:04.256+0200 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set CharmsDB-shard-0
2019-07-09T12:42:04.256+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set CharmsDB-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
```

I expect an established network connection but it doesn't let me connect to any.

Comment: Is this an M0 cluster? Are you still having this issue? In an M0, sometimes there are connectivity issues as reported by some people in https://serverfault.com/questions/955555/unable-to-reach-primary-for-set-cluster0-shard-0

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in Window's firewall. MongoDB uses port nr. 27017 so to make it work it **has to** be opened.

Also if u use Atlas, you can connect through their connection string. https://www.mongodb.com/